# Check if a string contains a specific sequence of characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, compare

I'm trying to check if a string contains a specific sequence of characters.
More precisely, I need to verify if my string has these characters:

```
A00[a-zA-Z]
```

So, I have a fixed part "A00" followed by one letter [a-zA-Z]. I have to identify if my "filename" string contains this sequence

```
filename -> A01k-test.rb   [KO]
filename -> A00W-test.rb   [OK]
```

I tried with this code

```
if @filename !~ /A00+[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    puts "OOOOOOOOOOK"
end
```

This code is not working, it doesn't match correctly.

Comment: That's because you are specifying that a string should not `!~` match this pattern and that the string should end after `[a-zA-Z]+` by using `$` try this `/\AA00[a-z]/i` this will assert that the string should start with `A00` then have one letter `[a-z]` and be case insensitive `/i`. matches no problem see [This Example](https://regex101.com/r/yV0iC6/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!~` (do not match) is the inverse of `=~` (match). You need to use the later for a match.

`$` is an anchor for the end-of-line or end-of-string in Ruby regular expression, which you don't need according to your post.

Try:

```
if @filename =~ /A00[a-zA-Z]/
  puts "OOOOOOOOOOK"
end
```

Comment: might want to add `\A` to the front of this regex since the file name should start with `A00` right now this pattern will match `A00` followed by any letter anywhere in the name so `dfA00df` will still match. Although the OP did not specify this his examples seem to suggest it.